# Decoding json data from back4app API

Tags: json, swift, back4app

I am having issues reading data from my back4app API into my swift project.I have connected my Back4app app to my swift project.Imported the necessary pods.

Below is how I connected my app to my swift project

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Parse

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.applicationId = "KwLoFN7Rik2qadAS6dSpnNIv5E0Qd1Uu0nhvO1dt"
            $0.clientKey = "RVNjTMvt5l73jt5GQxsg9GI16CDOiPAbEXiVPTY1"
            $0.server = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
        }
        Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
        return true
    }
```

This is the data model I am using to decode my json data.My json data follows this structure

```
import UIKit
struct restaurant: Decodable{
    let objectId: String
    let restaurant: String
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let calories: String
    let price: String
    let ImageUrl: String
    let type: String
    let createdAt: String
    let updatedAt: String
}

struct restaurants: Decodable{
    let restaurants : [restaurant]
}
```

In my viewdidload() method I check if my swift project has successfully connected to my back4app app and then I try retrieving the data using the url but I keep getting an error and I'm not sure what's it is

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var restaurantStruct : restaurants? = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        testParseConnection()
        if let url = URL(string:"https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/restaurants"){
            let session = URLSession.shared
            session.dataTask(with: url) { [self] (data, response, err) in
                guard let jsonData = data else {
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let artworkList = try decoder.decode(restaurants.self, from: jsonData)
                    self.restaurantStruct = artworkList
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print(self.restaurantStruct ?? " ")
                    }
                    print(self.restaurantStruct!)
                }
                catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Error decoding JSON", jsonErr)
                }
            }
            .resume()
        }
        
        
        
        func testParseConnection(){
            let myObj = PFObject(className:"FirstClass")
            myObj["message"] = "Hey ! First message from Swift. Parse is now connected"
            myObj.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
                if(success){
                    print("You are connected!")
                }
                else{
                    print("An error has occurred!")
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

This is the error that I see in my terminal

```
You are connected!
Error decoding JSON keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "restaurants", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"restaurants\", intValue: nil) (\"restaurants\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

using parse to read data

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"SoccerPlayers")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("HMcTr9rD3s") {
  (soccerPlayers: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil && soccerPlayers != nil {
    print(soccerPlayers)
  } else {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use `print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8))` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @burnsi This is the output I get `{"error":"unauthorized"}`

Comment: Well. Then this is not about decoding the JSON. You are simply not authorized.

Comment: how could I change this cut I have put in the app id and client keys in my app delegate file.Not sure why im unauthorised.Or is there a way I could make the API public

Comment: I think you should start reading the documentation for `Parse`. It seems you configure the `ParseClient` but try using the system URLSession. I don´t think it works this way. You probably need to use the `ParseClient`

Comment: You should not post your app id and client key. Those should now be considered compromised.

Comment: I have taken a look at the parse documentation and  the code block I recently added is what was advised to use to read data objects but the `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("HMcTr9rD3s") ` gives an error `type of expression ambiguous without more context` not sure what that means

Comment: Once you have some "valid" keys for your server, when you do a REST request
 typically you need to add your credentials to it, and some query parameters.
 Currently you only have a `url`. You need to use `URLRequest`.
 Look up `URLRequest`, and how to add the "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" and "X-Parse-Application-Id",
 using for example: `request.setValue("your-api-key", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thank you so much, I had been struggling.It all works fine now.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error like {"error":"unauthorized"}, you should use MasterKey but this dangerous for client side.

You can use sessionToken for authorized. But if you don`t know for now.

You can change CLP-Class level permissions from dashboard. You can open your app in back4app, and open the related Class. Do it public read and public write.